# python for loop is returning empty dataframe as results

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

I am dealing with a dataframe that includes several data for more than 60 years and 180 countries.

When I do this operation manually I have no problem:

```
data = data.loc[data['year'] == 1962]

results = data.pivot_table(index='origin', columns='sitc', values='export_val', fill_value=0)
```

However, when I use a for loop to process all my data at once, I'm getting as a results empty dataframes

```
for years in range(1962, 2015):

    data = data.loc[data['year'] == years]    

    results = data.pivot_table(index='origin', columns='sitc', values='export_val', fill_value=0)
```

This is the resulting dataframes:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: The first time through the loop, you select only the data for 1962 and assign it to `data`. The second time through, you try to get the data for 1963, but it is no longer in `data`. Try using a different variable like: `df2 = data.loc[data['year'] == years]` and then pivot `df2`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through the range, try using the lower and upper bounds to limit the data.

```
data = data.loc[data['year'] >= 1962]    
data = data.loc[data['year'] <= 2015]
```